# Recreate google inbox's ios plus button

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to recreate google inbox's plus button on a UITableView

Here's the image:
[image]

I want to recreate the red plus button on the bottom right in a UITableView. I've got an image which is the red button and I've tried just dragging a button onto the storyboard, but it orbits around the `contentView`. I can't move it to the bottom right.

I also tried adding a transparent `UIView` as a `subview` of my table view like so:

```
let transparentView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
transparentView.alpha = 0

let plusButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50))
plusButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "plus")
transparentView.addSubview(plusButton)

self.view.addSubview(transparentView)
```

The view just doesn't show up. Not sure whats wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to position it in the superview of your table view:

```
o View Controller
|
\---o View
    |
    +---o Red Button
    |
    \---o Table View
```

Try using the side bar in Interface Builder to get your red button to the right place in the hierarchy. If you need to insert a parent view to your table view, try using *Editor > Embed in > View*

Comment: My tableview is inside a uitableviewcontroller, so its not embedded inside a uiview... I'm actually using a `PFTableViewController`, so without changing my subclass I don't think I can embed it. Here are two screenshots of what it looks like when I try http://imgur.com/3fkMTwv,FM25nJk

Comment: that's why I never use table view controller--you can end up in situations like this. you could move your red button view to the window itself (or a view in the window.)

Comment: You could also create a custom subclass of *UIViewController* to act as a parent view controller for your table view controller.

Comment: I usually don't either, but Parse made it look so easy. How would I add it to the window? Do you mean I should add a subview to `self.window`?